# How to put string into table from a splitted line python

Tags: python

I have a code that read a files and split each line, the object if if to put the two elements in a new table where each table element is composed by the two split element like this:

```
tab = [
    ('football', 'sport'),
    ('element!', 'pyhsics'),
    ('coefficient', 'math'),
    ....
]
```

my file is composed by lines, each line contain two element separated by a tab

```
sport   football
Math    thermalization
Process thermalization
phsycis semi-classical methods
Process nuclear reactions
```

my code is:

```
from codecs import open
from contextlib import suppress
import logging

new_path = 'C:/learning/file'
new_days = open(new_path,'w')

div_texts = []
tab= []


with open("C:/learning/clea", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

for line in lines:
    div_texts.append(line.strip().split("\t"))



for i in range(len(div_texts)):
    try:
        new_days.write(div_texts[i][0])
        tab[i] = div_texts[i]
        print(tab[i])
        new_days.write("\n")
    except (UnicodeEncodeError,KeyError,IndexError):
        pass
```

here print(tab[i]) is not printing anything!

thank you for your help

Comment: While English proficiency is not required, a properly formatted question is expected.

Comment: The first thing to do is commenting out try-except-pass and observing an error

Comment: This is a little confusing, you are showing the output as a list of tuples but div_texts and lines are a list of strings.  That is not causing the failure to print.  Have you tried to see what div_text is?  My guess is that text is not a file or in the right place from scanning your code.  In other words, when you finish the run do something like div_text[0]

Comment: @AndreySScherbakov: if i will delete the tru except, there is empty line that will cause error

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
tab[i] = div_texts[i]
```

tab is empty so taking its ith index causes an IndexError exception that remains unreported because this code is inside a `try:` block catching such kind of exception and thus control flow immediately goes to the `except:` clause.

Try, for example, `tab.append(div_texts[i])` instead.